# Exporting report with more than 1200 pages to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

My report contains more than 1200+ pages and I want to export it into PDF. I am using ASP.NET.

Currently, exporting takes more than 2 hours. I'm using Pull method. How can i optimize this process?

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportsTest dsFams = new ReportsTest();
    string condition = Session["cond"].ToString();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        tblFA_ItemSetupTableAdapter tblItemSetup = new tblFA_ItemSetupTableAdapter();

        if (condition.Contains("{tblFA_ItemSetup.ParentCatID}"))
        {
            tblItemSetup.FillByParentCatID(dsFams.tblFA_ItemSetup, Session["holdbranch"].ToString(), Session["ParentCat"].ToString());
            ds.Tables.Add(tblItemSetup.GetDataByParentCatID(Session["holdbranch"].ToString(), Session["ParentCat"].ToString()).Copy());
        }
        else
        {
            tblItemSetup.Fill(dsFams.tblFA_ItemSetup);
            ds.Tables.Add(tblItemSetup.GetData());
        }

        Cache["dtImages"] = ds;
    }
    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/rptFA_ItemTag.rpt"));

    rpt.SetDataSource((DataSet)Cache["dtImages"]);
    CrystalReportViewer1.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = false;
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
}
```

This is on button click code:

```
rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/rptFA_ItemTag.rpt"));
rpt.SetDataSource((DataSet)Cache["dtImages"]);
System.IO.Stream oStream;
byte[] byteArray = null;
oStream = rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
byteArray = new byte[oStream.Length];
oStream.Read(byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oStream.Length - 1));
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Comment: can you provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to export to a PDF you don't need a report viewer. 
You can delete these 2 lines and save some rendering:
CrystalReportViewer1.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = false;
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;